# Is it possible to create custom effects for the android camera?

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to create custom effects for a camera app but I'm stuck on using effects other than the default effects.

Is it possible to create effects and use them in a similar way as I would use

```
cameraParams.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_POSTERIZE)
```

Comment: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: @shark Could you point me to some resources on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You have a very good [examples](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/)